# Only identify strings with upper AND lowercase

Tags: regex, powershell

I would like to use powershell to identify only strings that contain both upper and lowercase characters.

```
$param = "Sam"

If ($param -cmatch "[A-Z]"){
    Write-Host "String has uppercase characters"
}
```

This is what I have right now, but this only returns when uppercase characters exist in the string. I would like for it to return ONLY if both exist in the same string.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$param -cmatch "[A-Z]*.[a-z]" -or $param -cmatch "[a-z]*.[A-Z]"
```

You can try different patterns at http://regexstorm.net/tester

(Thanks to briantist and Keith Thompson for the updated patterns.)

Comment: This will fail on some strings, for example `k_F` or `I am.`

Comment: I think you need a `.*` between the two halves of each regexp (assuming powershell regexps are similar to the ones I'm used to).

Answer (score 1):

I would use:

```
if ($param -cmatch '[a-z]' -and $param -cmatch '[A-Z]')
```

It has to satisfy both matches, a single lowercase character somewhere in the string and a single uppercase character somewhere in the string.

Answer (score 0):

`Lookaheads` are supported in powershell. So you can use this regex

```
^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yE3lA7/2)**

*Powershell Code*

```
If ($param -cmatch "^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$") { Write-Host "String has both upper and lowercase characters" }
```